# Can I Run an Infinite Loop in the Background in an ASP.NET Core Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

Can I run an infinite loop at the end of startup.cs that is hosted in IIS? I have to run a loop every second infinitely once the application starts.

**Update**
Yes, I could. However, it turns out it's not a good design in my case when it's time for scaling with multiple instances and load balancing. In my specific scenario, I was able to resolve this simply by separating the infinite loop logic into a console app that doesn't require scaling regardless of traffic (by following good SOC).

Comment: AWS does provide services like Lambda for this kind of polling applications, so it is poor insights to resort to ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using ["Hosted Services"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to achieve what you want..

"[In ASP.NET Core, background tasks can be implemented as hosted services.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)"

Comment: Hosted services are usually deployed as Windows/Linux service apps, not web apps running on IIS.

Comment: Lex, have you read the documentation from the link ? The technology is named "hosted services" and allows you to write code for running background tasks within a Web app context.

Comment: Deploying hosted services in an ASP.NET Core web app on IIS is bothering yourself (similar to running Hangfire https://blog.lextudio.com/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a). Microsoft dislikes the idea to put everything in documentation, so the issues only bite you when you try it out.

Comment: Lex, that is an architecture / design decision - I just posted an answer to the original question; just that it is possible. Whether the original poster wants to use this or not is their decision. And Yes, I am aware of Hangfire as well. (any decision on these matters requires consideration of the project context ..)